# Can't 3D print my model

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

After ending the modeling process, I wanted to 3D print my model, I apply the solodify modifier, and whater I solidify or not, the resulting stl won't slice properly.
[image]

I have 468 non-mainford verts (don't know it it matters.)

[image]

If I add smooth modifier, I get weird results.

[image]

If I try to slice the .blend I shared on this post (exported as stl) [image]I shared here, holes can be seen.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend that you use Ultimaker **Cura** to slice 3D models, as it is a free and powerful program that supports almost all 3D-printers. It has never failed me yet.
[https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-connect](http://CURA)

Comment: In order for the slicer to have a good chance of properly slicing your model you'll want to try and give it a [manifold mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599), free from self-intersections, thin walls, etc. [This tutorial](https://i.materialise.com/blog/en/3d-printing-with-blender/) is a bit older but perhaps useful?

Comment: Already checked it. Didn't work